# Sampling of a real time-correlated random variable

Tags: time-series, sampling

I would like to sample numerically the real-value time-continuous random variable $X(t)$, which verifies:
$$E[X(t)X(s)]=f(t-s).$$

In my case, $f$ is given by
$$f(t)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}.$$

-My first idea was to use a Fourier series decomposition of the function $f$, and white noises for each mode. However, the fourrier coefficients are not always positive. As a result, I end up with a complex random variable $X$.

-My second idea was use Continuous Time autoregressive processes of increasing order (order $1$ at the first time step 1, order $2$ at the second one, etc..), and use the Yule-Walker equations. It is however very time-consuming..

Thank you for your help!